# iOS Transfer sizeable data via BLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to send a bit of data (32KB) between two iPhones (6+ and 4S). I understand BLE is not intended for large data transfers, but I'm certain there should be a way around my problem.

I have a characteristic setup as follows:

```
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:someID]
                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                        value:nil
                                  permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

To send it, I break it down into chunks and send it like this:

```
[self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunkOfData
                  forCharacteristic:myCharacteristic
               onSubscribedCentrals:aSubscribedCentral];
```

However I noticed that it takes a good 20 sec. to get the data through which doesn't really work for me... My question is: how can I achieve a reasonable speed?

Comment: What do you consider reasonable?  There are other answers on stackoverflow which suggest that 2000 up to somewhere below 4000 bytes/second is possible in low interference conditions.  If you want more, you likely can't get it on any iOS device due to it's allowed connection parameters.